# pyimagesearch.com - backpropagation algorithm. What is exactly the difference with the last two layers?

Tags: backpropagation

In one part of this tutorial, you could find the following lines:

```
for layer in np.arange(len(A) - 2, 0, -1):
```

Here, we start looping over the layers, backwards, to build the chain of derivatives. He stated the following with respect to not taking into account the last two layers:

```
# the last two layers are a special case where the input
# connections need a bias term but the output does not
```

What does this mean? The fact that when we are in the last (output) layer, as it is not a hidden layer, but the previous one is, we still need to specify the dimensions of the matrix in a way that is compatible with the previous layer having a bias weight but the current one doesn't?

Comment: Bias is included in the penultimate layer's input connections but omitted in the output layer, affecting weight matrix configuration and ensuring architectural compatibility. This underscores the broader principle of bias terms enhancing neurons' adaptability by providing an additional degree of freedom. Embedding bias directly into the weight matrix simplifies implementation and streamlines training.

Comment: The question should be self-contained. e.g. tutorial link: https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/05/06/backpropagation-from-scratch-with-python/ etc.

Comment: The other thing is length of A is number of layers + 1 = L + 1. The last layer is special and it's the output layer. But, the for loop accounts for L-1 layers. I believe saying last two layers are special is a bit confusing for the reader.